# Hibernate Logger Error for Hibernate-Search

Tags: hibernate-search

I have been getting Logger error for Hibernate-Search. 
I am trying with different versions, also with all possible ways, possible solutions, but no luck :(

Can any folks help me in resolving this? Am stuck in this for a week now.

We are using Spring Boot-2 and Hibernate 5. Everything works fine when run from eclipse with embedded Tomcat of spring-boot, but fails to build/run with bellow **error** **when deployed in External Tomcat in Linux server.**

***Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:*** **org.hibernate.search.util.logging.impl.LoggerFactory.make()Lorg/hibernate/search/util/logging/impl/Log;
    at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator.(HibernateSearchIntegrator.java:32)**
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 158 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you are using two different versions of Hibernate Search: one version for `hibernate-search-orm`, and another for `hibernate-search-engine`.

Pick one version, use it for both JARs, and you should be fine.